# Function to sum the values of base-2 numbers without using parseInt

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the sum of base-2 numbers. Is there a way to do this without using parseInt?

```
function calculate(num1, num2) {
     var a = parseInt(num1, 2);
     var b = parseInt(num2, 2);
     return a + b;
 }

calculate('101', '10')
//Returns 7
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/ko1wuq2u/1/

Comment: Any reason you dont want to use `parseInt()`

Comment: Checking to see if there is a different way if parseInt() is disabled. Also sometime, we can receive decimals.

Comment: I don't think `parseInt` can be disabled without disabling the rest of JS as well.

Comment: `parseInt` is one of JS core. Why and how do you think it's going to be disabled?

Comment: I must get really crazy exercises then

Comment: what if they want you to play on bits and not use number at all..  hint crazy exercise :)

Comment: Do you want the result to be `7` (base-10) or `111` (base-2)?

Comment: Result should be 7 (base-10)

Comment: It is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/vx606kLh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function calculate(num1) {
     var j=num1.length;
     var arr=num1.split('');
     var num=0;
     for(var n=0;n<arr.length;n++)
      {
          if(j>=0)
          {
             num=num+(Math.pow(2,n)*arr[j-1]);
             j=j-1;
          }
      }
        alert(num);      
 }
```

This should work,i haven't tested it fully.but should work!

EDIT:

This now directly adds the 2 numbers ,it should also work.

```
var d=calculate('11','101');
alert(d);

function calculate(num1,num2) {
    var h=((num1.length>num2.length)?num2:num1);
    var h2=((num1.length>num2.length)?num1.length:num1.length);
    var secondnum;
    if(h==num2)
        secondnum=num1;
    else
        secondnum=num2;
    for(var x=0;x<=(h2-h.length);x++)
    {
        h='0'+h;  
    }
     var arr1=h.split('');
     var arr2=secondnum.split('');
     var j=arr1.length;
     var sum1=0;
     for(var n=0;n<arr1.length;n++)
      {
          if(j>0)
          {
              sum1=sum1+(Math.pow(2,n)*parseInt(arr1[j-1]));   
              sum1=sum1+(Math.pow(2,n)*parseInt(arr2[j-1]));
              j=j-1;
          }
      }
return sum1;    
}
```

Comment: Is this possible with two give arguments?

Comment: @rainbowloops Only 2 arguments is fine?

Comment: @rainbowloops That will work but it can be more optimized,i will post a edit soon

Comment: @rainbowloops Check the update in the post,it is a better solution i guess.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define a bitwise math function, then a conversion function of your own. Example with comments:

```js
function binaryAdd(a, b) {
  // Break each string down into "bits"
  var aBits = a.split('').reverse(),
    bBits = b.split('').reverse();

  // Pad the shorter value with zeroes
  while (aBits.length < bBits.length) {
    aBits.push('0');
  }

  while (bBits.length < bBits.length) {
    bBits.push('0');
  }

  // Add
  var carry = false,
    out = [];

  // For each bit
  for (var i = 0; i < aBits.length; ++i) {
    var s = 0 + (aBits[i] === '1') + (bBits[i] === '1') + carry;

    // This acts much as a lookup table:
    // 0 and 2 should print zeroes, 2 and 3 should carry to the next bit
    out.push('' + s % 2);
    carry = s > 1;
  }

  if (carry) {
    out.push('1');
  }

  // Flip and join
  return out.reverse().join('');
}

function parseBinary(n) {
  // Get the bits
  var nBits = n.split('').reverse();

  // Sum using the value of each position
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nBits.length; ++i) {
    sum += nBits[i] * Math.pow(2, i);
  }
  return sum;
}

function showMath(a, b) {
  var c = binaryAdd(a, b);
  return '' + a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + c + ' (' + parseBinary(c) + ')';
}

document.getElementById('a').textContent = showMath('101', '10');
document.getElementById('b').textContent = showMath('10111', '1011');
```

```html
<pre id=a></pre>
<pre id=b></pre>
```

Comment: This doesn't return a number

Comment: @rainbowloops The `parseBinary` function does (so `parseBinary(binaryAdd(a, b))` will give you `7`, as desired). The `showMath` function is just there to show how the example works.